# Coefficients of the stirling's series expansion for the factorial.

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics, power-series, factorial, gamma-function

Knowing the Stirling's approximation for the Gamma function (factorial) for integers:
$$\Gamma(n+1)=n!\approx \sqrt{2\pi n}n^ne^{-n}\bigg(1+\frac{a_1}{n}+\frac{a_2}{n^2}+\cdots\bigg)$$
Using the above approximation one can write:
$$(n+1)!=\sqrt{2\pi(n+1)}(n+1)^{n+1}e^{-(n+1)}\bigg(1+\frac{a_1}{n+1}+\frac{a_2}{(n+1)^2}+\cdots\bigg)$$
We know that following recursion holds:
$$(n+1)!=(n+1)n!$$
One can rewrite this:
$$(n+1)!=(n+1)\sqrt{2\pi n}n^ne^{-n}\bigg(1+\frac{a_1}{n}+\frac{a_2}{n^2}+\cdots\bigg)$$
All this comes from: https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~b89089/link/gammaFunction.pdf (Page 8-9)
Then the author gives this expansion to calculate the $a_k$ coefficients when $n$ becomes large.
Comparing these two expressions for $(n+1)!$ gives
$$1+\frac{a_1}{n}+\frac{a_2}{n^2}+\cdots=\bigg(1+\frac{1}{n}\bigg)^{n+1/2}e^{-1}\bigg(1+\frac{a_1}{n+1}+\frac{a_2}{(n+1)^2}+\cdots\bigg)$$
Then he says, that after "classical series expansion" this equals:
$$1+\frac{a_1}{n}+\frac{a_2-a_1+\frac{1}{12}}{n^2}+\frac{\frac{13}{12}a_1-2a_2+a_3+\frac{1}{12}}{n^3}+\cdots$$
I don't understand how he got there. Only thing that came to my mind was, that as $n\to\infty$ $\big(1+\frac{1}{n}\big)^n$ goes to $e$ but then we are left with $\big(1+\frac{1}{n}\big)^{1/2}$. When i expand this into binomial series, i get:
$$\bigg(1+\frac{1}{2n}-\frac{1}{8n^2}+\frac{1}{16n^3}\cdots\bigg)\cdot\bigg(1+\frac{a_1}{n+1}+\frac{a_2}{(n+1)^2}+\cdots\bigg)$$
And I'm stuck here.

Or is there any other elementary way how to compute the coefficients $a_k$ of the stirling's series expansion for factorial/Gamma function?

Comment: That part is easy, just Maclaurin expansion of $\sqrt{1+x}$.

Comment: Have a look at https://dlmf.nist.gov/5.11.i (especially formulae 5.11.3--5.11.6).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> We expand the series up to terms of $\frac{1}{n^3}$. We obtain for $\left|\frac{1}{n}\right|<1$
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+\frac{1}{2}}e^{-1}}
> &=e^{-1}e^{\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}\\
> &=\exp(-1)\exp\left[\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{2n^2}+\frac{1}{3n^3}+\cdots\right)\right]\\
> &=\exp(-1)\exp\left(1+\frac{1}{12n^2}-\frac{1}{12n^3}+\cdots\right)\\
> &=\exp\left(\frac{1}{12n^2}-\frac{1}{12n^3}+\cdots\right)\\
> &\color{blue}{=1+\frac{1}{12n^2}-\frac{1}{12n^3}+\cdots}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

and applying the *[binomial series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)*

> we obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> &\color{blue}{1+\frac{a_1}{n+1}+\frac{a_2}{(n+1)^2}+\frac{a_3}{(n+1)^3}+\cdots}\\
> &\qquad =1+\frac{a_1}{n\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}+\frac{a_2}{n^2\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^2}
> +\frac{a_3}{n^3\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^3}+\cdots\\
> &\qquad =1+\frac{a_1}{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}\cdots\right)
> +\frac{a_2}{n^2}\left(1+\binom{-2}{1}\frac{1}{n}+\cdots\right)
> +\frac{a_3}{n^3}\left(1+\cdots\right)\\
> &\qquad\color{blue}{=1+a_1\cdot\frac{1}{n}+\left(-a_1+a_2\right)\frac{1}{n^2}
>  +\left(a_1-2a_2+a_3\right)\frac{1}{n^3}+\cdots}\tag{2}\\ 
> \end{align*}

Putting (1) and (2) together

> we obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> &\left(1+\frac{1}{12n^2}-\frac{1}{12n^3}+\cdots\right)
> \left(1+a_1\cdot\frac{1}{n}+\left(-a_1+a_2\right)\frac{1}{n^2}
>  +\left(a_1-2a_2+a_3\right)\frac{1}{n^3}+\cdots\right)\\
> &\quad\color{blue}{ =1+a_1\cdot\frac{1}{n}+\left(\frac{1}{12}-a_1+a_2\right)\frac{1}{n^2}
>   +\left(-\frac{1}{12}+\frac{13}{12}a_1-2a_2+a_3\right)\frac{1}{n^3}+\cdots}
> \end{align*}
>
> and the claim follows.

Comment: Seems fine, just the last line of (1). How did you change $\exp\bigg(\frac{1}{12n^2}-\frac{1}{12n^3}+\cdots\bigg)$ into $\bigg(1+\frac{1}{12n^2}-\frac{1}{12n^3}+\cdots\bigg)$

Comment: @MichalDvořák: We use the series expansion of $\exp(x)=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\cdots$ here with $x=\frac{1}{12n^2}-\frac{1}{12n^3}$ and we only need to expand up to the linear term in $x$.

Comment: @MichalDvořák: Many thanks for granting the  bounty.

Answer (score 3):

You were close. Note that<sup>1</sup>
$$
e^{-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+1/2}=1+\frac{1}{12n^2}-\frac{1}{12n^3}+\frac{113}{1440n^4}+\cdots\tag1
$$

Therefore, you have
$$
\bigg(1+\frac{1}{12n^2}-\frac{1}{12n^3}+\cdots\bigg)\cdot\bigg(1+\frac{a_1}{n+1}+\frac{a_2}{(n+1)^2}+\frac{a_3}{(n+1)^3}+\cdots\bigg)=\\
1+\frac{a_1}{n}+\frac{a_2-a_1+\frac{1}{12}}{n^2}+\frac{a_3-2a_2+\frac{13}{12}a_1+\frac{1}{12}}{n^3}+\cdots\tag2
$$
as per
$$
\frac{1}{n+1}=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n^2}+\cdots\\
\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}=\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{2}{n^3}+\cdots\\
\frac{1}{(n+1)^3}=\frac{1}{n^3}-\frac{3}{n^4}+\cdots\\
\text{etc.}\tag3
$$

---

Easy (but slightly cumbersome) exercise:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
{}&\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+1/2}=1\\
{}&\lim_{n\to\infty}n^2\left[e^{-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+1/2}-1\right]=\frac{1}{12}\\
{}&\lim_{n\to\infty}n^3\left[e^{-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+1/2}-1-\frac{1}{12n^2}\right]=-\frac{1}{12}\\
{}&\text{etc.}
\end{aligned}\tag4
\end{equation}

These are basic limits that are left to the reader.

Comment: Hang on, how did you come up with the first line?

Comment: @MichalDvořák I edited in a hint. Let me know if you need some more details. Cheers!

Comment: I would be interested in deriving the (3) formulas, I'm unfamiliar with these, i got the (1) and the limits (4)

Comment: @MichalDvořák Oh, it's pretty simple: $\frac{1}{n+1}=\frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{1+n^{-1}}=\frac{1}{n}(1-n^{-1}+n^{-2}-n^{-3}+\cdots)$ (just a geometric series in $n^{-1}$).  Can you take it from here?

Comment: Hang on, but Geometric series are $1+r+r^2+r^3+...=\frac{1}{1-r}$, while you have '+' sign here. What am i missing?

Comment: Just take $r'=-r$, so that $1-r+r^2-r^3+\cdots=\frac{1}{1+r}$

Comment: Oh, didn't see that, one last thing, how about the powers? $\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$... How do the coefficients 2,3 appear in here?

Comment: $$\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}=\left[\frac{1}{n+1}\right]^2=\left[\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{n^3}+\cdots\right]^2=\cdots$$

Comment: So just multinomial theorem? That came to my mind aswell, but found it pretty long. Ok I think this is it, thank you for your time!

Comment: @MichalDvořák That's it! No problem :-)

Comment: @MichalDvořák Instead of using the multinomial theorem, you can also use $\frac{1}{(n+1)^{a+1}}=\frac{(-1)^a}{a!}\left(\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dn}\right)^a\frac{1}{n+1}$ and differentiate term-wise.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72439/discussion-between-michal-dvorak-and-accidentalfouriertransform).